# Protractor : Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, gulp-protractor

I am facing an issue while launching protractor.

Below is the code that I am using:

**conf.js** with below code

```
// An example configuration file. 
exports.config = {
// The address of a running selenium server. 
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance. 
capabilities: {
   // 'browserName': 'chrome'
    'browserName': 'internet explorer'
},

// Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when 
// protractor is called. 
specs: ['example_spec.js'],

// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node. 
  allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1000000
}
};
```

**sample_class.js** file with below code:

```
 describe('angularjs homepage title check', function () {
        it('should have a title', function () {
            console.log('Step 1');
            browser.get('http://google.com');
            expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('My Todolist Page');
        });
```

Below are the commands I used:

1. Installed protractor and node js
2. webdriver-manager update --ie
3. webdriver-manager start

I'm looking for a working solution within Selenium, something like:

```
InternetExplorerOptions() { IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true} in selenium.
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Manoj welcome to Stackoverflow. What is your question or problem with this code?

Comment: As I mentioned in Title , i am unable to launch IE browser through protractor. I am getting "Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Pro tected Mode settings are not the same for all zones" error in console

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When you work with `Selenium 3.4.0`, `IEDriverServer 3.4.0` with `IE(v 10/11)`, you may consider configuring a couple of properties for IE to work as follows:

Along with setting,

```
InternetExplorerOptions() { IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true}
```

Consider the following:

1. **`Protected Mode`** Settings: On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the **Protected Mode** settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the **Protected Mode** settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled **"Enable Protected Mode"**.
2. **`Zoom Level`**: Set `Zoom Level` to **100%** for IE to work properly.
3. Add the following `InternetExplorerOptions()`:

   ```
   { ignoreProtectedModeSettings = true}
   { nativeEvents = true}
   { ignoreZoomSetting = true}
   { requireWindowFocus = true}
   { INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS = true}
   ```
4. Incase of ***IE11***: Additionally you have to consider the Registry Entries documented [**here**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is not going to help.  I am looking above solution in protractor c# and not for selenium